# where can a generic application write on an SD card?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, external-sd

I have a tablet running KitKat and face the problem of not being able to write to the SD card (specifically with `QPython`). I cannot root the tablet (yet).

My understanding is that an application can only write to a special directory which is created for the lifetime of the application in `/extSdCard/Android/data`.

Indeed, I can see there a bunch of directories, some of which have names which are the ones of my apps (it looks like a Java style way of naming, I do not know Java but I saw some spectacular stack dumps which had that nomenclature).

Now, I do not see anything close to `QPython`, which brings the questions:

- do all applications create by default this special directory?
- if yes: how can I match the name of the app to the directory?
- if no: is there a way for such application to write to the SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those questions is pretty easy to answer:

1. No, Android only creates those folders, if they are used. This is valid for both, *internal* SD and *external* SD.
2. There are many ways to get the package name (this is the internal name) of an app. The easiest way would be going to `http://play.google.com`(Google Play Store) on PC and opening the app's page there, then simply look at the last part of the url: e.g. `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus` (the `id=` part). For `QPython` this is: `com.hipipal.qpyplus`.
3. Every application can write to its own folder. Reading or writing to other folders on the *external* SD card requires special permissions.

Comment: Thank you. Re: 1: "if they are used" means "when the application requests to create them"? In other words if they are not created upon the installation of the application, it will not have the ability to write to the SD card ever? My `QPython` installtion did not create `/extSdCard/Android/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus` - does that mean that none of the scripts I will write (and which will be run by this app, inheriting its access rights) will have the capacity to write to the external SD Card?

Comment: Android automatically creates those folders when the app first tries to write to that folder. Make sure `QPython` has all the required permissions to do so.

Comment: I tried to create the directory from within the application (failed) and to directly write to a file within this non-existant dir (hoping that it would appear by miracle - but this failed as well).